# How to safely I check if a command/package is available at compilation time?

Tags: macros, packages, compiling

I want to produce a latex document that can compile with very few packages, let's say `xcolor` might be missing as an example (assume it is a document my bosses will compile and I do not control which packages they have installed and I must avoid compilation errors), but still I would like to safely use the command `\color` if the package is available. If possible I would like a solution that does not involve installing new packages.

To be more precise I would like to write this kind of document

```
\documentclass{article}

%%%%%% 
%%% Huge blobs of definitions 
%%% for \useIFpackage
%%% and \IFundefcommand
%%%%%%

\useIFpackage{xcolor}
\IFundefcommand{\color}[1]{}

\begin{document}
{
 \color{red} This package always
 compiles and if \emph{xcolor}
 is available this text should be red
}
\end{document}
```

Where `\useIFpackage{xcolor}` does nothing if `xcolor` is not available and `\IFundefcommand{\color}[1]{}` defines the command `\color` only if it is not already defined.

I suspect that this specific behaviour might not be possible, in that case I would appreciate if you could point me towards additional resources that *might* be useful/interesting for something similar.

Comment: As extra details: 1. a single-file solution would be best, 2. this is not essential (as I *can* ask to install packages) but I also feel like learning how to do this would be fruitful for my "mastery" of latex

Comment: There is the command `\IfFileExists`, which can be used to check if LaTeX can find a file (for example a package: `\IfFileExists{xcolor.sty}{We have it}{no}`) , but I can never remember if that triggers auto-install requests on MikTeX or not. To define commands which may be defined there is `\providecommand`, which won't change existing definitions.

Comment: I happen to dislike constructs like `\IfFileExists{xcolor.sty}{\usepackage{xcolor}}{<something else>}`, because they can (more or less) silently cause documents to look very different on different systems (and indeed even on systems that are extremely similar).

Comment: thanks for your answer, it solves my problem. If you want to post it as an answer I would be happy to mark it as accepted. For now I will use this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\IfFileExists{xcolor.sty}
  {\usepackage{xcolor}}
  {\newcommand{\color}[1]{}}

\begin{document}
  {\color{red} This package always compiles and if \emph{xcolor} is available this text should be red }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of doing such things I suggest inserting a comment into the .tex-source-files where system requirements for successful compilation are listed. I think well-establishing a common basis for interaction (regarding software/packages/tools etc in use) is much better than having different parties fiddle about with different makeshift solutions. Extreme scenario for exhibiting my point of view: What do you intend to do for avoiding discomfort for the boss in case the boss doesn't want to use a PC but an Android-based tablet-computer with no TeX Writer app installed? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @moewe for providing enough info in comments to help me find this solution.

For the example in the question I now believe this document should cover my use case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\IfFileExists{xcolor.sty}
  {\usepackage{xcolor}}
  {\newcommand{\color}[1]{}}

\begin{document}
  {\color{red} This package always compiles and if \emph{xcolor} is available this text should be red }
\end{document}
```

I had strange issues using `\providecommand`, but the else branch is a perfect place for a `\newcommand`in my case.